# How to add an int to a previously created buffer that contains a string

Tags: c, string, tcp, buffer

I'm trully sorry but did not know what to title it.

What I'm doing now:

```
char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
struct sockaddr_in *s = (struct sockaddr_in *)&addr;
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &s->sin_addr, ipstr, sizeof ipstr);
```

So if I print that I have the IP from the client that just connected to the server.

Now this is where I believe I'm doing it dumb. As of right now, I'm using that as an ID to identify the subscriptor (the client that just connected). But I have several problems with that, the main one being, what happens if by chance I get two address that are the same (as a dumb example, I'm using my own code carefully since I connect to myself thus using 127.0.0.1).

And I thought: I could put both address AND port to identify who is the subscriber.

And thus the idea of adding an int to that buffer. Obviously I'd have to create a slightly bigger buffer, but the thing is, I don't really know how to... "put" the int in there.

And please if anyone could tell me a better idea to identify clients/subscribers I'd be glad, I've thought of many stupid ideas and all give minor trouble like this.

To add to this, I know what number the port is after the creation of this buffer of course, so I thought of doing

```
char nombreSubscriptor[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN+sizeof(int)];
```

but if I did that I believe it wouldnt be space enough, once I change the int to string or char array or whatever.

Comment: Where is the code that you tried?

Comment: I formatted it wrong, changed it. I tried char nombreSubscriptor[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN+sizeof(int)]; Which I believe it's a pretty terrible idea (and it does not work obviously), but looking arround all I've found is looping through each number to put it into ansii and then putting that string/char array into the bigger one. And again, since I believe that all is just a poor idea I asked here @Deanie

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of the identification of the client? As some subscriber with which server will send information later on?

Each subscriber will have a unique connection with the server, isn't? I suppose you want to identify uniquely each client. You can track the connections with their socket descriptors.

You can also define a list of structs which contain the IP address of the client and the port of various clients that get connected to server instead of one array element encoded with IPAddr and port information.

Comment: yeah, Let me go little by little: Purpose of identificaction of client: so the server process can, when needed, as a client and make a connection to the client.||Yes, each subscriber will have an unique connection. I already can send and recv with each one separately.|| I already have a linked list of structs, inside the one I store IP, port, and a few other things (and can of course add anything needed, that's the reason I asked for other ideas since I believe identifying by address it's kind of dumb, 0 experience on this so not sure)

Comment: If all you want is a unique identifier per client, why not just create a new identifier upon connection, such as a GUID?